# Calculate hours needed to balance account?

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, accounting

I have an accounts excel sheet where you input all your expenses, all your incomes (gst inclusive), and it calculates how you are placed (E.G. -$717.75 for the month).

I It also gives you the gst content to pay `$taxableIncome*3)/23` and a rough guide as to how much income tax you should put away `$taxableIncome*0.17`.

You also tell the program what your hourly rate is.

I am wanting to add to the program to allow it to tell you that you need to work X more hours this month to balance.

This wouldn't be soo hard,

`$deficit/$hourlyRate = hours needed to work` except for each additional hour worked we need to add `($hourlyRate*3)/23` to the gst expense, and add `$hourlyRate*0.17` to the income tax expense.

This is the part I don't quite get how to work out.

So given an hourly rate of `$21.00+gst = $24.15/h` and a deficit of `$717.75` how can I work out how many more hours I would need to work?

> basically I am wondering how I can do a formula of
>       0 <= [(*x1+x2+x3*...)-(*y1+y2+y3*...)] / *z1*
>   Where *x1* must increase until the entire formula equals 0, but as *x1* increases, so must *y1* and *y2*
>   *x.* = Income Source
>   *y.* = Expense
>   *z.* = Hourly Rate (gst inclusive)

Note that while the excel formula would be useful I am not expecting people to do the work for me, just a generic overview in pseudocode will work.

Comment: I would take a look at Goal Seek. Depending on who is using your worksheet, this might work well for you. By which I mean if it's just you, you can manually use Goal Seek, if it's other people, you might want to automate it with some VBA.

Answer (score 0):

So, set:

```
gross new wage incl. gst - new gst - new income tax) = 
                                -(current income - current expense) or -(Y-E)
                                  where -(Y-E) >= 0

gross new wage - (gross new wage * 3/23) - (gross new wage * 0.17) = -(Y-E)

gross new wage * (1 - 3/23 - 0.17) = -(Y-E)

gross new wage = -(Y-E) / (1 - 3/23 - 0.17)

new hours * gross wage rate (incl. gst) = -(Y-E) / (1 - 3/23 -  0.17)

new hours = (-(Y-E) / (1 - 3/23 - 0.17)) / gross wage rate
```

That works, doesn't it?